# Trying to make bash server

Tags: linux, bash, http, netcat

I'am trying to make bash server. I need to handle only get requests. When i send a get reques. I could not get response. I can't understand why doesn't it work.

```
#!/bin/bash

port=$1
dir=$2



while true; do

request=$(nc -w 1 -q 0 -l $port)

 method=$(echo $request | awk '{print $1}')
 echo "Method: $method"
 resource=$(echo $request | awk '{print $2}')
 echo "Resource: $resource"

 if [ "$method" != "GET" ]; then
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\n\n<html><body><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></body></html>" | nc -w 1 -q 0 localhost $port
  continue
 fi

 if [ "$resource" == "/" ]; then
   resource="/index.html"
 fi

 file_path="$dir$resource"

 if [ ! -r "$file_path" ]; then
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n<html><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>" | nc -w 1 -q 0 localhost $port
 elif [ -d "$file_path" ]; then
  echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<html><body><h1>Index of $resource</h1><hr><pre>$(ls -l $file_path)</pre></body></html>" | nc -w 1 -q 0 localhost $port
else
 echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n$(cat $file_path)" | nc -w 1 -q 0 localhost $port

 fi
done
```

I tried to add -l flags to my responses. But then on first request you don't get a response. And on the second request you get response to previous request. And when i remove these flags i just can't get any responses

Comment: When you run `request=$(nc -l ...)`, you're setting up a listen port, getting a request, _and hanging up on the client_ before your script continues: by the time the next command runs `nc` has exited, so there's no connection still open; thus, your `echo`s certainly won't go back to that client.

Comment: Honestly, I'd advise not going this route at all: Use tools that start a copy of your bash script with its stdin and stdout connected to the client _after each client connects_. You can do that with xinetd, you can do that with... hmm, there's a TCP superserver from the runit/daemontools ecosystem, but I'm forgetting its name..., and I want to say that there's also support for that mode of operation in `socat`.

Comment: Ahh: http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html is the implementation from the runit ecosystem.

Comment: To be clear, you can build a toy service that looks like it works without a proper superserver that forks after receiving a connection -- and if you wanted to do that here I'd probably run `nc -l` _inside a bash coprocess_ so the single copy of `nc` stays open until you're done with it -- but doing that is going to be inherently, irreparably janky. There'll be time windows when the service isn't listening at all and incoming connections fail (because the shell hasn't gotten back to the point where it starts `nc -l` again); concurrent connections won't work; etc.

Comment: Check this project [bash-httpd](https://github.com/lewismc/bash-httpd) it's web server written in bash.